Do carbon fiber wings need a wing spar?
Considering the structural strength advantages of carbon fiber vs aluminum, would a carbon fiber wing need a wing spar?
I've seen some examples of some carbon fiber wings using some honey comb structure inside the wing, I've also see some use a spar, but don't know what the norm is.
Can the wing be designed with nothing on the inside, the same way a monocoque carbon fuselage is? or is it done this way already? what's the norm?

One must consider not only strength but also stiffness (to avoid flutter).  Fiberglass/epoxy over a foam core is done on model scale.  But not only materials, but also structure.  I would definitely do some homework, as the wing must be sound.

Small carbon-skin wings for race cars often omit a spar.  Sometimes their core isn't even rohacell honeycomb, just styrofoam.
Bigger wings like the A350's need a (carbon) spar, though.  Even larger radio-control model sailplanes with carbon wings can need a spar.

Yes that's actually how modern airliner wings are made, aluminum OR carbon. The entire "wing box" between the leading edge and flap/airleron is the "spar". The upper and lower wing planks, the top and bottom skins, are quite thick because they are the primary tension and compression members that do the job of a spar's top and bottom flange, or "cap" in a normal airplane (where the skin's only job is torsional stiffness and taking air loads).
On an airliner, what are called the front and rear "spars" are just the shear webs forming the front and aft walls of the wing box, which is its own spar. The advantages are less ribs, and great torsional stiffness, critical with long swept wings. To be efficient you need to make the wing in one piece so the entire lower plank is a continuous tension member from tip to tip. Making the wings in sections adds weight because of the need to create attachments that distribute the loads between adjoining members.
In either case you can use carbon in place of the aluminum in the same fashion.
The thick structural planks allow the rib count to be reduced because the plank needs less support. Carbon would allow you do reduce the rib count further as well as carrying the same loads with less weight. Potentially you could get to a rib-less carbon wing, but the weight saving won't be as much as you might think, because you have to make the plank quite thick in that case.


Oh ok yeah, seen so many pictures of airliner's wing and didn't realized the "wing box" was the "spar" itself lol. Yeah makes sense about the ribs not "needed"  with that design.

When you look inside the plank you see rows and rows of lateral stiffeners machined into the plank itself to make it stiff without being too heavy. On an aluminum wing you might see the rib count reduced by half or so.

Wing structures made of an external surface of carbon (or glass) fibers and an internal honeycomb structure are virtually ubiquitous in the rotating-wing world i.e. blades for helicopters and wind turbines. They are also used for the tailplane of several airplanes, not only small GA airplanes but also big ones: the tailplane of Concorde was a good example.

Blade section of a BO-105, the very first helicopter using glass fiber for the skin of the blade and foam for the core, first flight 1967 (figure source).
And the tailplane of Concorde points us toward some cons of this structural solution: The bond between the outer skin and the honeycomb structure is sensitive to manufacture and difficult to repair. Concorde suffered twice the separation in flight of the skin of the rudder, fortunately without any problem.
Anyway for the wing this solution is normally a no-go for another much simpler reason: If the internal volume is taken up by the honeycomb structure then there's no place left for the fuel.

"Is sensible to manufacture"?  Huh?  Did you intend a different word?

@CamilleGoudeseune They may have meant "sensitive" - a common false friend when translating from German

@Bergi: yep correct, thanks. I'm translating from another romance language

Yes, of course they do.
One aspect of a spar is the transmission of shear between the upper and lower caps. If you put unidirectional fibers on the wing skin at the chord of the largest thickness, you will still need a web to keep the two skins apart under load. Or you will end up like Willi Dirks did when he flew the first prototype of the DG-200.
The DG-100 is a standard-class glider derived from the Akaflieg Darmstadt D-37. It used an airfoil with almost 19% relative thickness at the root, but the DG-200 was designed as a racing class glider with flaps and a thinner airfoil of 17%. Willi nevertheless used the same layup for the spar, and with the higher shear caused by the smaller distance between the two caps, the spar collapsed when he flew into a gust at high speed.
If you use a sandwich skin for the wing, you will need to either put the unidirectional layers on the inside of the skin sandwich or to put a gap in the sandwich to transfer the shear stress between web and wing skin. Essentially, this will make the skin at the maximum thickness into spar caps and the web will complete the spar. If you use two webs spaced a bit apart, the resulting structure will form a torsion box - spar combination.
